# Stack overflow exception while reading graph .dot file with graphviz4net

Tags: c#, graph, stack-overflow, graphviz

I want to read graph from dot file with over `10000` nodes, but i get `stack overflow exception` in the same line.

I have tried this so far:

```cs
graph = Graphviz4Net.Dot.AntlrParser.AntlrParserAdapter<int>.GetParser().Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("graph.dot"));
graph = AntlrParserAdapter<int>.GetParser().Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("graph.dot"));
```

And i'm running out of ideas. Their documentation is not really abundant.

Comment: Just raise an issue on the library author's github. It's clearly a bug in the library (even if graph is malformed in some way - no library should ever throw stackoverflow exceptions).

Comment: @Evk their page is archived. Is there no alternative to graphviz4net? It appears its the only nuget package that allows loading .dot file, and saving it to nice format.

Comment: That I don't know - didn't work with graphs for a long time